# innodb_force_recovery doesn't set to zero [mysql]

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I'm trying to execute a simple insert query to mysql database, but it gives me this error:

```
 Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0.
```

I'm trying to set the innodb_force_recovery to zero, but it give me the same error. I tried to add the following line to the my.ini file under [mysqld]:

```
innodb_force_recovery=0
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried to set it from command line:

```
--innodb_force_recovery=0;
```

But again it didn't work. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: it must be set somewhere. grep -r innodb_force_recovery /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/*

Comment: check if you have /usr/my.cnf

Comment: I set it to 0, but now mysql does not start. This is the log error:
http://pastebin.com/GxGCgVFg

Comment: Don't expect that innodb_force_recovery > 0 will fix your InnoDB tablespace. This option is intended to ignore some errors so you are able to take a dump of your data

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25155777

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operation not allowed when innodb\_forced\_recovery > 0 \[SqlYog\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155777/operation-not-allowed-when-innodb-forced-recovery-0-sqlyog)

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs when MySQL is in read-only mode.

Edit file `/etc/my.cnf`, and comment out the following line

```
# innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

If you don't have access to the file, ask your administrator to fix it. When this line is commented out or does not exist, it reverts to a default setting of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Open my.cnf file in your server

> nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Step 2:

**Compare your file content**

[mysqld]

#innodb_force_recovery = 1

bind-address=0.0.0.0

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

Step 3:
After Making Changes Restart Mysql Server

> systemctl restart mysql