# Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0 [SqlYog]

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have created a table using SQLyog. When i insert values into it, it pops up following error message:

```
Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0.
```

My table consist only four columns including one primary key. 
Following is my create and insert queries:

```
CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `descr` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

insert into `test`.`news` (`title`, `slug`, `descr`)
 values ('titleOne', 'slugOne', 'descOne')
```

Comment: hi, can u share your create table ?

Comment: Question has been updated with create query.

Comment: because MySQL in read only mode. Open my.cnf file, set this parameter to zero and restart MySQL instance

Answer (score 20):

This error is comes when MySQL is in Read only mode.

Edit file `/etc/my.cnf`.

And comment out following line

```
# innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

Apparently this setting causes innodb to become read-only. If you don't have access to /etc/my.cnf on shared hosting, ask your host to fix it for you. When it's commented out or non-existent in /etc/my.cnf, the it reverts to a `default setting of 0`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me also but what i did was to change the SQL Engine during creatng the table from InnoDB to MyISAM
like in 
ENGINE=innoDB to ENGINE=MyISAM

So if  you have your database and want to upload it, open it with any editor and change the engine at the end of each table from innoDB to MyISAM.

this resolved the problem.