# Wordpress wp-admin redirects wp-login loop

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress wp-admin login page keeps on redirecting when i enter my login credentials and press login it comes to wp-login.php

when i enable wp-debug mode i found this error code.

```
WordPress database error: [Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0.]
UPDATE `pp_options` SET `option_value` = '1468499701' WHERE `option_name` = '_transient_timeout__redux_activation_redirect'
WordPress database error: [Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0.]
UPDATE `pp_options` SET `option_value` = '1' WHERE `option_name` = '_transient__redux_activation_redirect'
WordPress database error: [Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0.]
INSERT INTO `pp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_doing_cron', '1468499671.5349268913269042968750', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
```

Help me out in this issue

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operation not allowed when innodb\_forced\_recovery > 0 \[SqlYog\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155777/operation-not-allowed-when-innodb-forced-recovery-0-sqlyog)

Answer (score 0):

Edit file /etc/my.cnf

Take out comment in:
 # innodb_force_recovery = 1

In any case, wipe you cache (try to open in [private window](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/launch-start-private-browsing))

Check this [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue/) too.

Hope Works :)