# Redirect login issue into all my localhost WordPress sites

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

It happens on localhost for all my sites when I login I write the correct username and password but I get no error and the page just refreshes and won't let me into the WordPress dashboard.

For example I write:

`http://localhost/business_theme/wp-admin`

And I get:

`http://localhost/business_theme/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbusiness_theme%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

I also tried deleting the characters from `?redirect...`, cleaning cookies but still it redirects.

Any ideas on how I can login to my WordPress sites again on localhost?

Comment: check the site name and url on the wp_options table also check the wp_config  also checking the permissions on your user meta table

Comment: Take a backup of your current database and rename the plugin folder name. It will deactivate all plugins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operation not allowed when innodb\_forced\_recovery > 0 \[SqlYog\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155777/operation-not-allowed-when-innodb-forced-recovery-0-sqlyog)

Answer (score 2):

If your local site is the direct-copy of the site online, then this is just the case. WordPress redirects the page because it is **trying** to let you access the **guessed-very-correct** URL as the one you installed WordPress.

Open your database controller, find the table `wp_options`. Find the columns with `option_name` named `site url` and `home`, change the `option_value` to the corresponding URL in your local environment.

If not, there must be something wrong internal with your WordPress, turn on the debugging mode, and this will allow you more hint on this.

Comment: The sites am I taking about are only localhost or were first installed on localhost with wordpress. I checked the urls and they both looks correct to me: http://localhost/business_theme (the urls are both the same)

Comment: @Light_Warrior right, this can be a case, see my update.

Comment: Thanks I found the issue: WordPress database error: [Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0.]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_doing_cron', '1485855060.4561419486999511718750', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in debug mode:

```
WordPress database error: [Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0.]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_doing_cron', '1485855060.4561419486999511718750', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
```

I just needed to set innodb_forced_recovery = 0; in "my.ini" file